# Count most frequent element in an xml tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

I am trying to write an xsl code to view the Journal Name with most occurrences. I tries googling it but could'nt understand most of it(I'm new to xslt). Can anyone help me with this?

My XML(only one entry):

```
<Bibliography>
  <row>
    <Title>Title-B-0</Title>
    <Author>Jason Adair</Author>
    <Year>2015</Year>
    <Publication_Name>ACM</Publication_Name>
    <DOI>533/49</DOI>
    <Date>6/2/2021</Date>
    <Journal_Name>journal-s</Journal_Name>
    <Journal_Volume>9</Journal_Volume>
    <Journal_Issue>8</Journal_Issue>
    <Conference_Name></Conference_Name>
    <Conference_Location></Conference_Location>
    <Book_Title></Book_Title>
    <Book_Editor></Book_Editor>
  </row>
</Bibliography>
```

My XSL approach:

```
<xsl:variable name="maximum">
    <xsl:for-each select="//row">
        <xsl:sort  select="count(//row[@Journal_Name=current()/@Journal_Name])" order="descending" />
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

Most occuring value of journal is: <xsl:value-of select = "$maximum" />
```

Also, in a YouTube tutorial I was watching, the guy ran the xml in the browser and it was styles automatically but when I did it, I couldn't. Do new browsers no longer support xml and xsl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a *grouping* question. Assuming you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor, it would be best to use a variation of the [Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Here's a simplified example:

**XML**

```
<Bibliography>
    <row>
        <Journal_Name>journal-a</Journal_Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Journal_Name>journal-b</Journal_Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Journal_Name>journal-c</Journal_Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Journal_Name>journal-b</Journal_Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Journal_Name>journal-c</Journal_Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Journal_Name>journal-d</Journal_Name>
    </row>
    <row>
        <Journal_Name>journal-b</Journal_Name>
    </row>
</Bibliography>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="row-by-journal" match="row" use="Journal_Name" />

<xsl:template match="/Bibliography">
    <output>
        <!-- for each distinct journal name -->
        <xsl:for-each select="row[count(. | key('row-by-journal', Journal_Name)[1]) = 1]">
            <!-- sort by group size -->
            <xsl:sort select="count(key('row-by-journal', Journal_Name))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="Journal_Name" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>journal-b</output>
```

---

Note that in case of a tie this method will return only one of the top values.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but the solution does not work. It prints blank closing output tag only. I'm using [free formatter xsl-transformer](https://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html) for this.

Comment: There was a typo - try it now.

Comment: When I used "." to print out the contents instead of "Journal_Name" in the `xsl:value-of`, it printed out the contents of second `row`

Comment: Still the same sir. I corrected the typo first time around during execution

Comment: You can see it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEdvib

Comment: Yes sir, thanks a lot. It works :D The fault was on my end, your solution is flawless.